# Как отключить проверку сайта на javascript

Tags: javascript, python, веб-программирование

Когда я шлю запрос на свой сайт через python3 requests
Мне вместо содержимого сайта выводиться html код с тем что мой браузер не поддерживает js.
Кто знает как отключить ?

Comment: Никак. . . . . .

Comment: Никак.  Ваш «браузер» таки действительно не поддерживает js

Comment: А почему тогда когда я пытаюсь получить содержимое google.com то все хорошо, а с моим сайтом нет, ведь там даже нет js

Comment: меняйте браузер

Comment: «Там» это где? У гугла нет, у вашего сайта очевидно есть

Comment: @AlexeyTen, скорее имелось ввиду, что у него на сайте нет js